# Update WHERE Field IN

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sql-update

I've this working query:

```
SELECT idVendRigMov
FROM VendRM
WHERE idArtPromo IS NULL AND
      (idArtCategoria NOT IN (SELECT idArtCategoria FROM VendScontiCatEscl WHERE idVendSconti=2) OR idArtCategoria IS NULL) AND idVendTesMov=1
```

that return a list of "idVendRigMov";

I need to do update on each row of this result, like this:

```
UPDATE VendRigMov SET Sconto='7' WHERE idVendRigMov IN (result of previous query);
```

I've tried this:

```
UPDATE VendRigMov SET Sconto='7' WHERE idVendRigMov IN 
(
SELECT idVendRigMov FROM VendRM WHERE idArtPromo IS NULL AND (idArtCategoria NOT IN (SELECT idArtCategoria FROM VendScontiCatEscl WHERE idVendSconti=2) OR 
idArtCategoria IS NULL) AND idVendTesMov=1
)
```

but I obtain this error:
"The definition of table "VendRM" prevents operation UPDATE on table 'VendRigMov'"

How can I do this query?

Comment: Are you sure these are tables and not views?

Comment: VendRigMov is Table, VendRM is View..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`VendRM` is probably a view that refers to the table `VendRigMov`.  If so, you can fix this problem by using an additional level of subqueries.  Your query is:

```
UPDATE VendRigMov
    SET Sconto = '7'
    WHERE idVendRigMov IN (SELECT idVendRigMov
                           FROM VendRM
                           WHERE idArtPromo IS NULL AND
                                 (idArtCategoria NOT IN (SELECT idArtCategoria
                                                         FROM VendScontiCatEscl
                                                         WHERE idVendSconti=2) OR 
                                                               idArtCategoria IS NULL
                                                        ) AN
                                idVendTesMov=1
                          )
```

This should work:

```
UPDATE VendRigMov
    SET Sconto = '7'
    WHERE idVendRigMov IN (select idVendRigMov
                           from (SELECT idVendRigMov
                                 FROM VendRM
                                 WHERE idArtPromo IS NULL AND
                                       (idArtCategoria NOT IN (SELECT idArtCategoria
                                                               FROM VendScontiCatEscl
                                                               WHERE idVendSconti=2) OR 
                                                                     idArtCategoria IS NULL
                                                              ) AN
                                      idVendTesMov=1
                                ) t
                          )
```

This forces MySQL to instantiate the subquery.  When instantiated, you no longer have the problem of the outer-referenced table being immediately accessed in the subquery.